# Create Space Delimited File in Python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

Using the code below, I'm getting the correct information to the file - kind of.  Here's the code:

```
filename = raw_input('What would you like to name the file? ')

import csv

data = [frames]
out = csv.writer(open(filename,"w"), delimiter=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
out.writerows(data)
```

This generates something that looks like this in a text file:

```
"[255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0]" "[  0 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171
 171 171]"
```

I would like the information to look like this:

```
255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 []0 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The 2 brackets represents a character that indicates a new row of information.  It's a little rectangle on my text editor and I'm unsure of what the character is.

So, how do I get rid of the quotes and brackets and use this other character?

EDIT:

I tried using the code below and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)   
  File "backandforth3.py", line 154, in (module)
    out.write(' '.join(frame)) 
Type Error: sequence item 0: expect string, numpy.int32 found
```

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that!  I will get those updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Notepad as your text editor? Unix-style newlines (`\n`) show up as boxes in Notepad because it only supports Windows newlines (`\r\n`). That said, this should provide the output you're expecting:

```
filename = raw_input('What would you like to name the file? ')

with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
    for frame in frames:
        out.write(' '.join(str(num) for num in frame))
        out.write('\r\n')
```

There's no reason to wrap `frames` in another list; assuming that variable is a list of lists of numbers, as the expected output would indicate, this should work fine.

Also, if you absolutely have to have the "boxes" that you described in the output, replace `'\r\n'` with `'\n'`.

Comment: I think we can assume OP would rather do this with `csv`.

Comment: @JoelCornett, his input appears to be simple enough that the `csv` module is overkill. Numbers don't need to be escaped when the delimiters are spaces and newlines.

Comment: I tried that code and it gave me an error.  Please see edit above.

Comment: I see, you're inputting a numpy array. I've edited my code to fix that issue.

Comment: `print >>out, 'abc'` will write `abc\r\n` on Windows if the file is opened in `w` mode. Your code would work only in `wb` mode

Comment: That's correct; I was only testing that code on Linux, my bad. Updated.

Comment: @Fraxtil That seems to be exporting exactly, however, I was wondering what a good text editor would be for this type of programming.  There's something else going on when I try to import the space-delimited file into another program.

Comment: I recommend Notepad++ for Windows. It provides (among other things) some useful functions that deal with converting line breaks, which might be helpful in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If `frames` is a numpy array than you could use [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) function:

```
numpy.savetxt(filename, frames)
```

To fix your `csv` code open the file in binary mode `wb` to avoid corrupting end of lines, and don't wrap `frames` in another list it seems to be already a 2D array:

```
import csv

with open(filename,"wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(frames)
```